# Sharepoint online cannot change content type from folder

Tags: document-library, content-type

Up until a couple of months ago, we were able to change content-type of folder to a customised folder.  We are no longer able to do this, content-type is not even showing in the details pane any more, it used to be.

These SharePoint sites are all created as a result of creating Teams.

We have allow management of content-types set to yes at the library level for all of these sites.

Does anyone know if there has been a setting changed that would have caused this and how to rectify this?

We are desperate to fix this, if anyone knows the answer, that would be fantastic.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: We are seeing the same issue. It appears to be just a UI change in the modern view, as we are able to change the Content Type of an existing document or folder if we switch to class view.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am able to now implement this as a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft acknowledge this was a temporary issue and it should now be resolved - see https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/content-type-in-details-panel-of-sharepoint/m-p/1318767#M40223

Relevant comments from Microsoft from the Microsoft Tech Community about this issue:

"We are currently investigating this behavior"

"This should be solved by now."

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/107267)

Comment: @Gaurravs there wasn't any detailed information about the issue in the link. It was an internal issue with Microsoft's SharePoint Online platform. Microsoft made no public incident statement that I can reproduce here.  I've added the relevant quotes from the link.

Comment: What other information about the issue would you consider relevant?